# How can I sort the output of model.predict function from Keras?

Tags: python, numpy

I have built a Sequential model to predict dataset. The output is an array of values something like below:

```
[[25.672846 ]
 [35.517834 ]
 [16.25976  ]
 [27.06339  ]
 [15.176579 ]
 [20.261982 ]
 [17.346558 ]
 [14.3797455]
 [23.327494 ]
 [17.967245 ]
 [17.85637  ]
 [16.672417 ]
 [ 6.2621603]
 [20.35404  ]]
```

I want to sort the array in ascending order.

I've tried

```
pred = np.sort(model.predict(data))
```

and

```
pred = np.argsort(model.predict(data))
```

and I've failed.

Comment: This is a Numpy array sorting question, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `Keras` (tags edited).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `np.sort` as follows:

```
pred = np.sort(model.predict(data), axis=0)
```

Default behaviour is `axis=-1` which is equivalent to `axis=1` in  your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the array in the number you can use the below

```
pred = model.predit(data)
pred.sort() 
print(p)
```

This will show sorted preds. By default, the sort is in ascending order

if you want the index of the sorted

```
pred = model.predict(data)
sorted_index = pred.argsort(axis=0)
print(sorted_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `np.reshape(x, -1)` before sorting. This way you will have a flat array which is something you might want to do eventually after sorting anyway. This is why I would prefer this over specifying the axis which is otherwise a good solution too.